# Problem with creating SSAS Roles using Powershell

Tags: permissions, ssas, powershell, role

I'm using powershell to (mass) delete and create roles in SSAS. Deleting is done like this :

```
$rolecount = $db.Roles.count
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rolecount; $i++) {
        Write-host ($db.Roles.item(0).name) 
        $db.Roles.item(0).Drop([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DropOptions]::AlterOrDeleteDependents)
    }
$db.Update()
```

and adding like this :

```
        if (!$db.Roles.Contains($sRole))
        {
                $db.roles.add($sRole) > $null
                $role = $db.Roles.GetByName($sRole)
                $role.update()
        }
        else
        {
            Write-host "[$((get-date).ToString('HH:mm:ss'))] -> Role '$sRole' already exists !"
        }
```

with **$db** being an instance of the "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database" class. When the role is added permissions etc. are added too in a similiar fashion. 98% of the time that works fine, but ever so often i get the following error message back from SSAS : `the object (database role) with the name [insert role name here, its always a different one] already exists in [insert database name here]` (i translated the error message, actual wording in english could be different). The script output shows that the same role has been deleted moments ago with no errors. I even put a debug output into the script that counted the number of roles after deletion, it was 0. Has anyone experienced this behavior before ? i've tried for ages to find a way to reliably reproduce the error in order to fix it.

Comment: can you post the exact script? In your delete script for example you iterate i=0, i<rolecount but you keep deleting item(0) instead of item(i)

Comment: yes, it always deletes the first item, the second then becomes the first, repeat

Comment: I see makes sense

Comment: If you trap this error in a try/catch block and retry the add operation do you get the same error again or does it clear on the retry?